# How to await multiple Promises?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, ecmascript-next

I have following code, `fileStatsPromises` is of `Promise<Stats>[]`, both `foo` and `bar` are `Promise<Stats>[]`. What is the correct way to await them? I want to get `<Stats>[]`.

```
    const files = await readDir(currentDir);
    const fileStatsPromises = files.map(filename => path.join(currentDir, filename)).map(stat);

    const foo = await fileStatsPromises;
    const bar = await Promise.all(fileStatsPromises);
```

EDIT: a minimal example.

```
function makePromise() {
    return Promise.resolve("hello");
}
const promiseArray = [];
// const promiseArray = [] as Promise<string>[];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    promiseArray.push(makePromise());
}

(async () => {
    const foo = await promiseArray;
    const bar = await Promise.all(promiseArray);
})();
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Your code is pretty incomplete. Could you provide an example that can actually be run (including a definition of `stat`)? Apart from that, if `fileStatsPromises` is an array of Promises, you should be fine with your second option (`bar`).

Comment: This seems to be a bug caused by typescript, because the console actually outputs 10 'hello' when I log `bar`.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

This is correct:

```
const bar = await Promise.all(promiseArray);
```

`await Promise.all([...])` takes an array of Promises and returns an array of results.

`bar` will be an array: `['hello', ..., 'hello']`

You can also deconstruct the resulting array:

```
const [bar1, ..., bar10] = await Promise.all(promiseArray);
console.log(bar1); // hello
console.log(bar7); // hello
```

There are a few similar functions you can use depending on your use case:

- [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) - waits for all to resolve or any to reject.
- [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) waits for all to resolve or reject.
- [`Promise.any()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any) waits for any resolve or all to reject.

Comment: @Everyone_Else the question asks for TypeScript as well.  Plus this is valid JS (ES2017) and works in recent versions of Node.js 7 and 8.  If you need an older version of JS, you can run your source through something like Babel.

Comment: `Promise.allSettled` is probably also worth mentioning in this context.  Documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

Answer (score 2):

Please use `Promise.all()`.
Please refer the official documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all