# How can I wait for a response using Axios and Typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, asynchronous, axios

I need your help to adjust my methods to wait for a axios response. Basically, I send a request to an WebService and I need wait the response to catch the return and call another method.

I've tried to use async/await on my calls but I probably used it wrong.

```
class PlaylistController {
  // Metodo inicial para criacao da playlist
  public async create(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> {
    let artists = req.body.bands;
    artists = artists.split(',');

    const search = await Object.values(artists)
      .map((artistsName): Promise<AxiosResponse> => this.searchArtists(artistsName));
    console.log(search);

  }

  private searchArtists = async (artistName): Promise<AxiosResponse> => axios.get(`${API_URL}/search`, {
    params: {
      q: artistName,
      type: 'artist',
    },
    headers: {
      Authorization: `${TOKEN_TYPE} ${REFRESH_TOKEN}`,
    },
  }).then((response): AxiosResponse => { console.log(response.data.artists); return response; })
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error.response.data); return error; });
}
```

This code first log the result of the "console.log(search);" with this output:

```
[Promise { pending },
 Promise { pending },
 Promise { pending } ]
```

After that is showed the axios response.

Comment: Your first `await` is simply awaiting the result of the `map` function, which is synchronous and returns immediately. If you want to wait for all of the promises to return, use `Promise.all`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I await a list of Promises in JavaScript/TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360567/how-do-i-await-a-list-of-promises-in-javascript-typescript)

Answer (score 2):

Your "**create**" function is not returning a promise, its a void return type function.
Also, you need to add await before async task like "**Axios**". Object.values is not an async task.

```
class PlaylistController {
    // Metodo inicial para criacao da playlist
    public create(req: Request, res: Response): void {
      let artists = req.body.bands;
      artists = artists.split(',');

      search = Object.values(artists).map((artistsName): any => this.searchArtists(artistsName));
      console.log(search)
    }

    private searchArtists = async (artistName): Promise<AxiosResponse> => {
        return await axios.get(`${API_URL}/search`, {
            params: {
              q: artistName,
              type: 'artist',
            },
            headers: {
              Authorization: `${TOKEN_TYPE} ${REFRESH_TOKEN}`,
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but got an error because the get() returns string|Promise and it doesn't match the function's return type